# Como mostrar certos produtos ao carregar num link para outra página?

Tags: php, html

Estou a ter um problema, por mais que tente não consigo o resolver..
O problema consta em:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="containercompras">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img class="imagem" src="images/imgbox1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="descricao">
                <div class="contentdescr">
                    <h2>Sombras</h2>
                    <p><a href="aaa.php" name="versombras">Ver mais</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img class="imagem" src="images/imgbox2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="descricao">
                <div class="contentdescr">
                    <h2>Rimel</h2>
                    <p><a href="">Ver mais</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Na parte onde tenho para **ver mais** supostamente ao carregar deveria ir para outra página e mostrar certos produtos, que os vou buscar da base de dados.
Eles na outra página funciona perfeitamente, só não consigo fazer que ao carregar em "Ver mais" vá para a outra página e mostre somente aqueles produtos de uma só categoria..

Na outra página fiz assim para todas as categorias e deu:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
include("ligabd.php");

if (isset($_POST['sombras'])) {
    $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='1'";
   ...
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso, colocando parâmetros no seu href para pegar na página onde você quer que liste determinados itens. Por exemplo assim:

Vou usar o pedaço do seu código do itens "Sombras"

```
<div class="descricao">
                <div class="contentdescr">
                    <h2>Sombras</h2>
                    <p><a href="aaa.php" name="versombras">Ver mais</a></p>
                </div>
```

No href da linha `<p><a href="aaa.php" name="versombras">Ver mais</a></p>` você adiciona um parâmetro de identificação, como exemplo, vou colocar o parâmetro **?id=1**, ficando assim:

```
<p><a href="aaa.php?id=1" name="versombras">Ver mais</a></p>
```

E assim você adiciona em quantos links tiver (mas recomendo um cont++ ou outro atributo caso seja vários tipos de itens).

Então na página "aaa.php" você pode notar que ao clicar em *Ver mais* o link estará "aaa.php?id=1". Então você usa essa linha na sua página

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Essa linha irá pegar o valor (inteiro) correspondente ao seu parâmetro da URL (no caso da sombras, irá pegar o valor 1), então você coloca isso no seu query do sql, ficando assim:

```
    $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='$id'";
   ...
```

Então sempre que você for clicar num link, a página onde vai listar esses itens, irá fazer uma pesquisa no banco de dados usando o parâmetro de identificação da URL para fazer a requisição específica, e irá listar certinho e bonitinho na página.

O código completo fica assim:

**index.php:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="containercompras">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img class="imagem" src="images/imgbox1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="descricao">
                <div class="contentdescr">
                    <h2>Sombras</h2>
                    <p><a href="aaa.php?id=1" name="versombras">Ver mais</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img class="imagem" src="images/imgbox2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="descricao">
                <div class="contentdescr">
                    <h2>Rimel</h2>
                    <p><a href="aaa.php?id=2">Ver mais</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**aaa.php**:

```
<?php
//inicia session
session_start();

//header
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');

//inclui o arquivo do banco
include("ligabd.php");

//pega o id do item no link
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

//listar as compras
  $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='$id' ";

//query para imprimir as buscas
  $faz_procura = mysqli_query($link, $procura);
?>
<html>
  <body>
      <table id="itens" border="2">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td>Preço</td>
              </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php

//while para listar todos os dados baseados no ID_CATEGORIA
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($faz_procura)){
    ?>

    <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id_produto'] ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $row['nome_produto'] ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $row['preco_produto'] ?> </td>
    </tr>
  <?php }; ?>

    </tbody>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!! Mas na parte do código  ---> $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='$id' "; (Pag. aaa.php) como é que ele vai buscar os produtos da categoria 1, sendo que está "id_categoria='$id' "? Pelo o que você disse, teria que acrescer essa linha de código, ou mudar a que referi na pergunta? (pág aaa.php)

Comment: Assim Ana, você viu que no link está aaa.php?id=1 ?? Você viu que tem depois do (?) do php um parâmetro? No php você consegue passar valores pelo link, e dentro da página você consegue chamar o valor desse parâmetro, por isso está  WHERE id_categoria ='$id' ", pois o $id vale 1(pq no link está aaa.php?id=1 <-) e o php está lendo isso, você enxerga id_categoria = '$id', mas o PHP sabe que o $id está valendo 1, então ele enxerga id_categoria = 1, entendeu?

Comment: Faça um teste, na página aaa.php, escreve logo abaixo do $id = (int) $_GET['id']; isso aqui: echo $id; Acesse os dois botões de "ver mais" e você irá ver que ele mostra na tela, o número 1 no "Sombras" e o número 2 no "Rimel"

Comment: Sim eu testei e deu, mas só se apagar a resto do código " if (isset($_POST['sombras'])) {
  $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='1'";
 }elseif (isset($_POST['rimel'])) {
  $procura = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='2'";   ------ E eu necessito deste código para quando ir à página aparecer os produtos todos, mas entretanto como você disse funcionou, a minha questão agora é, como integro isso no meu código de modo a que não apague o que tenho feito?

Comment: Eu neste momento simplesmente meti a parte do código que você sugeriu por cima do "if(isset($_POST['sombras'])) { $procura= ... }

Comment: Sim sim, mas foi intencional a remoção desta parte, pois ao meu entendimento você usava ela para ver se quando selecionasse o "ver mais" do "sombras" pesquisasse por id_categoria=1, e consequentemente pelo 2. Essa busca só vai buscar equivalente ao item que clicaste no index.php. Não sei se fui claro, mas não precisa mais usar o isset.

Comment: Faça assim, me diga qual é o ID equivalente ao item Sombras no seu banco de dados.

Comment: O ID do item sombras na minha base de dados é 1
Você me ajudou bastante até agora, eu é que não estou a conseguir integrar no código!
Mas se eu nao tiver o isset ao carregar no botão não aparece nenhum produto ...

Comment: Façamos assim, poste todo o seu código do aaa.php, só para eu analisar toda sua sintaxe.. Pois to achando que deve ter um "}" perdido.. Por isso da erro de sintaxe e falha total no PHP.. Daí não lista nada.. Atualize sua pergunta com todo o aaa.php para ajeitarmos

Comment: Já postei, se conseguir me ajudar agradecia imenso, isto é a minha prova final do curso! Postei como resposta à minha própria pergunta, esqueci de atualizar a pergunta...